# how to calculate monthly values from daily values with respect to the numbers of days for each month in excel?

Tags: excel

I have some daily values  for the year 2000 look like:

```
 A   B          C 
     daily   monthly
 1   0.5       .
 2   0.2       .
 3   0.4       .
 4   0.6       .
 .    .
 .    .
 .    .
366  0.8
```

I want to calculate as a monthly with regard to the number of days for each month in the year 2000?
any hints please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=B2 / DAY(DATE(2000,MONTH(DATE(2000,1,1)-1+A2)+1,1)-1)
```

- `DATE(2000,1,1)-1+A2` will get the day represented by A.
- `DAY(DATE(2000,MONTH(DATE(2000,1,1)-1+A2)+1,1)-1)` will get the number of days in that month.

Note the year 2000 was a leap year, so the last record should actually be day 366, not 365.

Comment: surely you need to subtract the start of the year from A2? I.e. =A2-DATE(2000,1,0)

Comment: @barryhoudini I'm not sure I follow what you're saying. Try the formulas - they work.

Comment: @barryhoudini Umm, that would give you a negative date-value.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, my mistake

Comment: I copy/paste the formula to C2 column and I drag down but I got 366 values not monthly sum

Comment: it is like A2 is divided by B2

Comment: @WafaAlyaari You didn't *say* you wanted a monthly *sum*. You wanted to "calculate as monthly". Are you saying you want 30 copies of the same value?? You're probably better off making a pivot table to do this.

Comment: sorry to have confused you.calculate as monthly means sum all values for the first month and write the answer,then do the same with all values but in respect to the number of days of months in 2000,so finally, will get 12 values instead of 366 values.

Comment: Then just use a pivot table and use `MONTH(DATE(2000,1,1)-1+A2)` to get the month.